# Proving completeness of $L^p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

I want to make sure my understanding of the proof is correct.

For a Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $L^p$, we want to find a $f\in L^p$ such that $f_n\stackrel{L^p}\to f$

Now, skipping the technicalities of the proof, if we manage find *some* $f$, for which $$\forall \epsilon>0\;\exists n_0,\; m\geq n_0 \;\;\|f-f_m\|_{L^p}\leq\epsilon$$
Are we done? I'd say yes, as, $f=\underbrace{(f-f_m)}_{\in L^p}+f_m \in L^p$ and $$\epsilon \geq \|f-f_m\|\geq \Big|\|f\|-\|f_m\| \Big|$$
Implies $\|f_m\|\stackrel{L^p}\to \|f\|$

Am I correct in my reasoning?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. This is just the definition of convergence in $L^p$: $f_n \rightarrow f$ if $\|f-f_n\|\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: The measure theoretic definition: $$ 
L^p(X,\mu):=\{f:X\to\mathbb R:\ \|f\|_{L^p}<\infty\},$$

Comment: @Potato I was not aware of the definition, nor do I see the need for such definition, Am I missing something, or is this perhaps not needed if you start with the measure theoretic definition of $L^p$?

Comment: What Potato wrote is simply an equivalent definition of completeness. As to your question, you are done after the fourth line. The fourth line is the definition of convergence and $L^p$ is complete if every Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$ converges. That is, if there is an $f\in L^p$ which satisfies what you wrote in the fourth line.

Comment: @VincentBoelens It's not a definition of completeness, it's a definition of convergence. In a metric space, a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ if $d(x,x_n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Potato Oops, you're right of course.